# Passing python method's reference to C as callback

Tags: python, python-c-api

Can we pass a reference of python method as an argument to C. This method is a callback method which will be executed after the C code has been executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python C-API, Python objects are simply `PyObject` references. `PyObject` references can be called using [PyObject_Call](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html?highlight=callable#PyObject_Call) (if you want to have more descriptive errors, you can call [PyCallable_Check](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html?highlight=callable#PyCallable_Check), first.)

Assuming you've extended a module using the API you would have a method as follows:

```
bool call_method(PyObject *method)
{
    PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
    if ( NULL == PyObject_Call(method, args, NULL) )
    {
        // Method call failed
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, in Python, you call the method using the following:

```
import my_module as bla

bla.call_method(myClass.myMethod)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is the same kind of thing possible in JNI as well ?

Comment: I've never used the Java Native Interface before, a quick search returned this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746078/implement-callback-function-in-jni-using-interface