# Whats the meaning of Left of '-> NewGlobalRef' must point to struct/union?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

To implement a C callback to java code using JNI, I followed the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746078/implement-callback-function-in-jni-using-interface) and [here](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/327) and adapted my native method implementation to store a reference to the objects I need for the callbacks later:

```
JavaVM * g_vm;
jobject g_obj;
jmethodID g_mid;

//More code here

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_a_B_initialize(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    g_obj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
    jclass g_clazz = env->GetObjectClass(g_obj);
    if (g_clazz == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find class");
    }

    g_mid = env->GetMethodID(g_clazz, "callback", "(I)V");
    if (g_mid == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to get method ref");
    }
```

However, this does not compile and I get the error messages:

```
Left of '-> NewGlobalRef' must point to struct/union
Left of '-> GetObjectClass' must point to struct/union
Left of '-> GtMethodID' must point to struct/union
```

I do not understand these error message. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you, perhaps, forget an `#include`?

Comment: My include looks like this: #include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "a_B.h"
Should there be more?

Comment: Can you paste the full output of the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use the C++ interface. You've tagged the question [C] so I assume you are using C.

In C, do it this way:

```
(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the JNI include:

```
#include <jni.h>
```

Comment: I added the include statement, but I still get the exact same error messages.