# How to handle DLL events in java project used JNI?

Tags: java, events, java-native-interface

I made Java project using JNI(Java Native Interface).

Java load a DLL file.

the DLL fires Events.

How to handle DLL events in Java program?

When the DLL event is fired, I want to call specific method.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Do you have code to share from your DLL event logic and your corresponding Java classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a callback for your native code which corresponds to a method within a class instance or a static method on the Java side.

See [this example for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746078/implement-callback-function-in-jni-using-interface)