# Return function pointer from C++ behavior to Java object with JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, function-pointers, swig

This is way over my head so here we go.

I am setting a function pointer in C++ with an interface Java object which looks like that on the Java side:

```
    Info_t info_t = new Info_t();
    info_t.setCallbackTest(new CallbackTest() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(int num) {
            System.out.println("callback: " + num);
        }
    });
```

where `CallbackTest()` is the interface with just one method:

```
public interface CallbackTest {
    void onCallback(int num);
}
```

and `setCallbackTest()` refers to the Java native method which is reflected in the C++ side like that:

```
JNIEnv *gbl_env;
jmethodID gbl_method;
jobject gbl_callback;

void WrapperFunction(int a) {
    gbl_env->ExceptionClear();
    gbl_env->CallVoidMethod(gbl_callback, gbl_method, a);
    if(gbl_env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
        gbl_env->ExceptionClear();
    }
    return;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_apiJNI_Info_1t_1callbackTest_1set(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jobject jarg2) {
    Info *arg1 = (Info *) 0;

    (void) jenv;
    (void) jcls;
    (void) jarg1_;
    arg1 = *(Info **)&jarg1;
    {
        jclass clazz;
        jmethodID mid;

        clazz = jenv->GetObjectClass(jarg2);
        mid = jenv->GetMethodID(clazz, "onCallback", "(I)V");
        if(mid == 0) {
            std::cout << "could not get method id" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        gbl_env = jenv;
        gbl_method = mid;
        gbl_callback = jarg2;
    }
    // here I am setting function pointer to the helper method which invokes the java code
    if(arg1) (arg1)->completionCB = WrapperFunction;
}
```

All of this was written basing on the [Implement callback function in JNI using Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746078/implement-callback-function-in-jni-using-interface)

I have tried calling the `onCallback()` method defined in Java on the C++ side and it works (just like in the link above) but now I am trying to set the value on such `struct` under C++

```
typedef void (*callbackFunction)(int);
typedef struct Info
{
    callbackFunction    completionCB;
    void                *caller;
} Info_t;
```

so later on at some point I would like to get the `callbackFunction completionCB` back to Java as an object and probably do various stuff with it.

My question is how can I return/map the function pointer behavior from C++ back to the Java object? Basically, I would like to do the same but in the reverse order. I am able to map Java interface onto function pointer now I would like to map function pointer behavior onto Java object.

EDIT: So far I have come up with such getter for it but I am not sure how to proceed

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_apiJNI_Info_1t_1callbackTest_1get(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_) {
    jobject jresult = 0;
    Info *arg1 = (Info *) 0;
    callbackFunction result;

    (void)jenv;
    (void)jcls;
    (void)jarg1_;
    arg1 = *(Info **)&jarg1;
    result = ((arg1)->completionCB);

    {
        jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass("com/CallbackTest");
        ???
    }
    ???
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not cache the JNIEnv value.

Per [Chapter 5: The Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) of the JNI specification (bolding mine):

> **Attaching to the VM**
>
> **The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
>   thread**. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
>   first call `AttachCurrentThread()` to attach itself to the VM and
>   obtain a JNI interface pointer. Once attached to the VM, a native
>   thread works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native
>   method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls
>   `DetachCurrentThread()` to detach itself.

For method id and your callback object, you need to create a global references:

```
    gbl_method = jenv->NewGlobalReference( mid );
    gbl_callback = jenv->NewGlobalReverend( jarg2 );
```

That does create one serious problem, though - that object reference held in `gbl_callback` will result in the Java object never getting garbage collected.

To return a C++ callback function, you'd first need to convert the function pointer to a valid Java type.  Strict conformance with the C standard (JNI is really C and not C++, so passing objects back and forth gets a bit murky when you mix in C++) means you can't treat the function pointer as anything other than a series of bytes, which means you'd need to convert the function pointer to a Java byte array and return that to Java.  Then convert that Java byte array back to a function pointer when you want to use it in native code.  That's a lot of code, and in JNI the more code you write the more likely you'll break something - JNI is *fragile*.

But on both Windows and POSIX, a function pointer will fit into a `jlong`, and a `jlong` can accurately represent a function pointer's value, so that's a hack that works (and under POSIX it's probably not even a hack, but I'm not going to try finding the actual POSIX function pointer specifications that would allow that cast).

The easiest way to do that is to create a `long` field in your Java object, and *return* the function pointer cast to a `jlong`:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_apiJNI_Info_1t_1callbackTest_1set(
    JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jobject jarg2)
{
    ...

    return( ( jlong ) WrapperFunction );
}
```

That would be called something like this:

```
// Info_t has a long field called callback
Info_t info_t = new Info_t();
info_t.callback = info_t.setCallbackTest(new CallbackTest() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(int num) {
        System.out.println("callback: " + num);
    }
});
```

In my experience, the less JNI calls you make, the better.  So if you can pass a value via a parameter or return it from a function call, that's simpler, safer, and a lot more reliable than trying to get/set object field values with JNI calls.

But then you'd need to pass the callback value as another parameter:

```
// function pointer, returns void, takes int arg
typedef void (*funcPtr)( int );

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_apiJNI_Info_1t_1callbackTest_1get(
JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong callback, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_)
{
    funcPtr f = ( funcPtr ) callback;

    f( 4 );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you reffering to the part of the code where I defined global `JEnv*` and did `gbl_env = jenv;`? If you do then how else can one map Java interfaces to the function pointers in C++?

Comment: @Lisek The quote in the answer already outlines what needs to be done. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026030/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-jnienv/30026231#30026231) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That points out the flaw of my code but still looking for the answer how could I map function pointer to the Java object.

Comment: @Lisek *That points out the flaw of my code but still looking for the answer how could I map function pointer to the Java object.*  There is no way to call non-JNI type functions such as your `void WrapperFunction(int a)` directly from Java code.  However, you can save function pointers as `jlong` values.  See edits for details.